# Minecraft Hunger Games late-game strategy

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have played several games of [Minecraft hunger games](http://mc-hg.com), and have been pretty consistently been able to reach the top 10 by dispatching any enemies with a quickly-crafted stone sword, then immediately focusing on iron armor.

Commonly the game reaches a point where there are only a handful of survivors, each who most likely have full iron armor. Right around this stage, the feast is announced it will arrive shortly, giving their coordinates. My questions are:

- What's a good strategy to guarantee you'll get the items at the feast?
- Is it better to declare your presence at the feast area (stand in the middle, watching your back), or attempt to hide out, waiting for another person/group to come?
- What's an effective kit to have to contend with any feast competitors?

I think understanding this stage of the game is vital, since each time I've lost to someone who happened to get the diamond armor/sword at the feast before I arrived.

Comment: Hmm...I didn't know there were "craft-able" MCHG servers.

Comment: New users: this question is asking for answers from *experience*. Just vague opinions about how to do it, without having ever done it yourself, are not going to be very helpful for someone who already has experience and is trying to figure out the late-game strategy.

Answer (score 3):

I have found that two things can be helpful.

1. A fishing rod can be used to give yourself a split second advantage on running for the cornucopia by using it to slow down others.
2. also, i like to wait on the sides of the clearing around the feast until others come. Then, when they fight each other swoop in and kill the winner of a battle when he is weak. Most people will be wounded from the battle making them easy pickings.

Answer (score 2):

I [play Hunger Games](http://www.uberminecraft.com/index.php) all the time since I got kind of sick of creative and regular survival. I usually hang back and wait for the crowd to thin out, looking for armor and other stuff until I can sneak in and finish some other people off. I don't win all the time, but I have a good average on leader boards for the servers I play on.

Answer (score -1):

At the beginning I would try to get a stone sword, food, and a pick axe, and don't focus on killing anyone – just go straight underground and mine. If that technique
doesn't work then start the same but just focus on killing people so they don't ever get full iron armor, and any iron/leather armor they do have, you can take for yourself.

Comment: This isn't a chat forum, so back-and-forth discussion doesn't happen/gets deleted. An answer should be a self-contained solution to the question to fit the Q&A format. If you want to chat with people, try [chat] instead of using the business end of the site for chatting. (I've edited this to remove the invitation for discussion.)

Answer (score -2):

I think you should just craft a stone sword and hide out underground, and when the feast comes you may be able to just make a run for it there and get the diamonds and other items that will help you win the game. Sorry if my answer isn't very good, I've never heard of the feast but this sounds like a good way to win the survival games.

Comment: Not much point in posting an answer if you have no actual knowledge.